# Que se vean correctamente los saltos de linea al utilizar Textarea

Tags: laravel-5

Tengo una tabla Articulo, que entre sus variables esta `$texto`, y que al crear, una fila, se solicita el valor de esta variable mediante `textarea`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero tras haberlo creado, me encuentro con esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Habia colocado un par de saltos de linea, pero al mostrarse en pantalla, HTML lo traduce como un solo espacio.
Así es como muestro el texto del Articulo:

```
<h3 class="text-left">{{$articulo->texto}}</h3>
```

¿Como lograria que se muestre de forma que respete los saltos de linea que introduje en el formulario?

Más información: Algo que probe es el uso de la etiqueta `<pre>`, que permite que se muestre el texto en su estado original.

```
<h3 class="text-left"><pre class="text-left">{{$texto}}</pre>
```

Pero me da este resultado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Obviamente, desearia que el usuario no tenga que estar pulsando una barra para ir leyendo todo el texto. ¿Como hago para que se muestren los saltos de linea, pero viendolo todo en pantalla?

Comment: Debes hacer los saltos de línea con \n

Comment: Pues eso no funciona. Se muestran los \n en pantalla.

Comment: Extrañamente, probe lo que dices pero con <br>, y da el mismo fallo.

Comment: intetastes con el <br/>

Answer (score 1):

Ya encontre una solución:

```
<span class="{{$eficiencia}} text-left" style="white-space: pre-line;">{{ $u->ocupacion->descripcion }}</span>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias a esto al fin he logrado que se muestren los saltos de linea.